# MySQL Table and Data Missing after odd crash

Tags: mysql

Bit of an odd problem here, on my development server I suddenly started getting access denied for all users.

I restarted the machine and once back in all the tables and data I've added this week has completely disappeared.

If I do mysqlcheck it does actually show the tables in the list, but I can't query them etc.

I'm aware there are some solutions posted on google but i'm not a DBA and I could REALLY do without messing this up if there's a way I can restore this, any suggestions on how to do this safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what worked for me was:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqlcheck -u USER_NAME -p --auto-re
pair --all-databases
```

Tables and data are now back.

I'll leave this question open for anyone that actually understands MySQL in depth to explain the why's / how's for some points!